# Looking for a simple way to place lat-long data from a csv file on a map (google or whatever)?

Tags: google-maps, geolocation

Given a csv file with lat-long data I am looking for a simple way to place it on a geo map.

There seems to be quite a choice in this area, so I am a bit perplexed as to where to start.

I have no prior experience with geo services, so please be gentle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need any further requests, when you have lat's and lng's, you may use this to create the marker(guess that's what you want to do)

```
//assuming you've parsed the CSV-data 
//and converted them into an array

for(var i=0;i<csvData.length;++i)
{
  new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(csvData[i].lat,csvData[i].lng), 
        map: mapObject
    });  
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I really like http://cartodb.com/ -- you can upload your CSV file and immediately start browsing the points on a map.  It's a full PostGIS database, so you can do a lot more.

Google's FusionTable's is also a super-fast way to get a CSV file with lat/long on a Google map:  https://www.google.com/fusiontables/Home/

In both cases, you can geo-code, embed the map, etc.  I use these when I get CSV data that I want to look at or share with a client, once you have an account (free), you can go from CSV to a map in less than a minute.

Comment: Thanks Tac! Over three years later and this is still the best answer (and should have been the accepted one).